# Copying text into minicom doesn't get pasted completely

Tags: console, serial-port, embedded-linux, serial-communication, minicom

I am trying to paste a line; which is:

```
setenv -p STARTUP "ifconfig eth0 -auto;boot -z -elf 136.170.195.87:vmlinuz-nfs-7231b0-D183-NFS-DEBUG 'root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=136.170.195.87:/export/home/joshis1/vmlinuz-nfs-7231b0-D183/rootfs/nfs rw bmem=226M@30M ip=dhcp'"
```

When I try to copy the line in `minicom`, the line is not copied completely.

What should I do?

Comment: It would help if you could show what portion is copied.  Also, it's possible that if you are dealing with a true serial port at a low baud rate, the program might refuse to buffer more than a certain number of characters beyond what it has managed to send, and so drop part of something that it pasted in.  So for example, it would be interesting to do a test where you use a loopback cable but no peripheral, and try posting your line both at 300 baud and at whatever the highest rate you can set it to is (>= 115200)

Answer (score 7):

I have solved this by setting Character tx delay to 1ms.

Ctrl+A followed by z
select 't'
select 'f'
type '1'

and there you go!

Comment: Any way to do this through command line, without issuing CTRL commands?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you are running without line wrap on? I had a problem until I started invoking with "minicom -w". In the problem condition, output line content beyond screen width was lost, input line content wrapped to beginning of line.

If I'm not wrong you should exit minicom, start it again with "minicom -w".

Comment: Great. I suggest you accept the answer, that will add to both our reputations. Ref http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

Or even better, try using 'screen' instead of 'minicom'.  I gave up minicom a long time ago in favor of screen.  Once you get used to it, you'll never go back!.  Chris Stratton was probably right: you're overrunning the target.  There is no flow control in virtually all embedded targets.  That said, I do these copy operations from screen all the time using screen to set u-boot environment variables, and never have any issues.  Depends on your target, too!

Invoke screen something like this:

```
screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
```

Of course, the device node corresponding to your serial port will be different depending on your serial device.  The example above is typical for Linux with a USB serial dongle.  On my macbook, it usually comes up as something like this for the same serial dongle:

```
/dev/tty.usbserial
```

If you like vi, you'll love screen.

Answer (score 1):

I do like the suggestion of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17390480/813810) to use screen.

However, if you want to keep using minicom an option is to enable both `Software flow control` and `Line wrap`.

To enable `Software flow control`:

- press `Ctrl+A` followed by `o`
- go down to `Serial port setup` and enter it
- press `g` to switch `Software Flow Control` to `Yes` (if not previously enabled)
- press `Esc` and select `Save setup as dfl` if you want to permanently save the configuration

To enable `Line wrap`:

- press `Ctrl+A` followed by `o`
- go down to `Screen and keyboard` and enter it
- press `r` to switch `Line Wrap` to `Yes` (if not previously enabled)
- press `Esc` and select `Save setup as dfl` if you want to permanently save the configuration

Line wrapping can also be enabled by starting minicom with the `-w` option or by pressing `Ctrl+A` followed by `w`.